# Low voltage shut off

Tags: low-voltage

I have some temperature controllers that run on 110V. They get 110V from a generator pushing 480 three phase through a transformer to get 110V. The controllers have issues if the voltage drops too low as in the generator runs out of fuel or if the generator is turned off before killing power to the controllers. As the generator is winding down the voltage is getting lower and lower till it is zero.
Is there a device I can put inline to throw a switch or relay if the voltage gets too low, say 90 to 100 volts?

Comment: Google for Under-Voltage-Breakers or Under-Voltage-Cutouts

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a "protection relay", specifically one with low voltage release.  These come with various levels of functionality, from fixed release voltages, to manually adjustable with a screwdriver, to fully digital with a display and other monitored parameters like line frequency.

Comment: Thank you for the help